# Can't install ubuntu or any linux distribution on laptop because of sudden shutdown

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, shutdown

I have been trying to install ubuntu, mint and fedora but my laptop always shutdown during the installation. 
Microsoft windows runs fine on my laptop without facing such an error, it only happens with any linux distribution

Currently i'm running windows 7 and i want to replace it with ubuntu 18, but i can't get to the boot menu to install it. Sometime i get to see the installation steps but it always shutdown

Note: it runs on my battery without a problem for some time then it shutdown!

Note: i always get the acpi errors at startup.
Any idea?

Update: i opened the laptop today and i cleaned the dust but i'm still facing the problem. It has nothing to do with overheating.

Here is a video showing the problem

https://youtu.be/12ltjoQ1z7I

laptop: hp 250 g4

Processor: i3 4005u

Memory: 4 gb ram

Video card: R5 330m 2 gb

Comment: How do you know it's shutting down?  Is the system powering off. or is it just not displaying anything?  (We need more information that your video does not really provide)

Comment: Sounds like a poweroff in the last second of the video, which indicates faulty hardware -- usually either overheating or power supply. Diagnosing your hardware has nothing to do with Ubuntu, so we're not going to do that. DO NOT try to install Ubuntu on faulty hardware.

Comment: The system power off. If you listen carefully at the end of the video, you should listen to a sound of shutting down

Comment: If it is shutting down as a result of overheating, try disabling turbo in the BIOS. When was last time you cleaned the vents and such on the laptop? (I have to do mine at least twice a year, in a relatively clean environment.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's overheating. When i run windowss, my cpu usually around 45°~50 °

Comment: Plus, this problem only happens when trying linux

Comment: I tried a different charger but i still face the same problem. However it doesn't shutdown when running on my battery for longer period compared to when the charger is plugged in!

Comment: I believe the sound at the end of the video is the sound of my hdd. Could it be a bad sector?